# Trying to filter some Elasticsearch results where the field might not exist

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have some data and I'm trying to add an extra filter that will exclude/filter-out any results which is where the key/value is `foo.IsMarried == true`.

Now, there's heaps of documents that don't have this field. If the field doesn't exist, then I'm assuming that the value is `foo.IsMarried = false` .. so those documents will be included in the result set.

Can anyone provide any clues, please?

I'm also using the .NET 'NEST' nuget client library - so I'll be really appreciative if the answer could be targeting that, but just happy with any answer, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, within elasticsearch, for a boolean field, if the field doesn't exist, it doesn't mean that it's value is false. It could be that there is no value against it.

But, based on the assumption you are making in this case - we can check if the field `foo.isMarried` is explicitly false `OR` it does not exist in the document itself.
The query presented by Rahul in the other answer does the job. However since you wanted a `NEST` version of the same, the query can be constructed using the below snippet of code.

```cs
// Notice the use of not exists here. If you do not want to check for the 'false' value,
// you can omit the first term filter here. 'T' is the type to which you are mapping your index.
// You should pass the field based on the structure of 'T'.
private static QueryContainer BuildNotExistsQuery()
{
    var boolQuery = new QueryContainerDescriptor<T>().Bool(
        b => b.Should(
            s => s.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.foo.IsMarried).Value(false)),
            s => !s.Exists(ne => ne.Field(f => f.foo.IsMarried))
        )
    );
}
```

You can trigger the search through the `NEST` client within your project as shown below.

```cs
var result = client.Search<T>(    
    .From(0)
    .Size(20)
    .Query(q => BuildNotExistsQuery())
    // other methods that you want to chain go here
)
```

Comment: Hi @saigummaluri - thanks heaps for answer! I'm going to start trying it now. Question though - you said this: > "for a boolean field, if the field doesn't exist, it doesn't mean that it's value is false. It could be that there is no value against it." .. So does this mean that I don't need to check if the field exists? So my query _could potentially_ be simpler?

Comment: Yes, could be. Usually, if a field is null, elasticsearch does not add it to the inverted index and hence, you do not see that field in the document. In your case, that boils down to how you have that handled on the data insertion part. If you want to make it simpler and not check for value == false, you can omit the terms filter in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **should** query with following conditions.

1. IsMarried = false
2. must not exists IsMarried

```
POST test/person/
{"name": "p1", "IsMarried": false}

POST test/person/
{"name": "p2", "IsMarried": true}

POST test/person/
{"name": "p3"}

Raw DSL query

POST test/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "IsMarried": false
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "IsMarried"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you can convert this raw DSL query to NEST!

Comment: can we make it even simpler and say "married.ismarried MUST NOT == true"? that way we include both false and null.